# Change state from other component (without passing setState function)

Tags: react-native, components, state, setstate

I have a quite decent background in android but now I am starting digging into react native and I am really confused with the ways to change the state of a component through hooks and set state function.

To the point, I have my main screen and I have many small components which change visibility. This is done by letting the user change some filter settings within dialogs. So the suggested way to do that is by having a hook in my main screen with a list that holds the values for the visibility of each component. But since I change the visibility of the components from inside the modals, every time I want to show a modal I will have to pass in a different function(for example setComponentEnable or setComponentDisabled) to set the state for each component. So my main screen will be polluted from all these small functions. Also I should not forget to mention that my modals are consisted from many smaller components and I will have to pass as deep as it goes the proper function to match the user action.
So my question is, is there a way to do this thing without polluting my main with all these small functions and make it possible for the main screen to update every time the user change the filters within the modals?

I already read about context but the docs say:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.

So I dont think that this should be a great case for context use.
What I am trying to do now is create a hook with a list

`const [isibility, setVisibility] = useState([]);`

create visibility handler functions

```
const setVisibilityEnable = () => {
   ...
}
```

and pass it into my modal.

```
<MyModal 
     visibilityHandler={setVisibilityEnable}/>
```

Is there a way to manipulate the state without passing all these callbacks to the modals? Or maybe is there anyone that can suggest a better and clean solution to avoid end up having a really huge main screen?

Answer (score 0):

you can include all the settings in one object and pass that object to all the components. Then each component will then modify that object accordingly.

```
const defaultVisibility = {
                            childComponentOne: true,
                            childComponentTwo: true,  
                          };
const [visibilityObject, setVisibilityObject] = useState(defaultVisibility);
```

pass both the function and the object into your child components:

```
<ChildComponentOne visibilityObject={visibilityObject} setVisibilityObject={setVisibilityObject} />
```

Then in your child component, you set the visibility like so:

```
setVisibilityObject({...visibilityObject, childComponentOne: false});
```

Comment: This is exactly the same approach like the one I am using now with the only difference that you use an object instead of an array. But the problem still exists here because if there are a couple of extra conditions that I also need to check when the user changes the visibility then I need to write several small functions and pass them in the modal.

Comment: maybe give us a little bit more code to see how exactly is this approach polluting your main component?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just pass a property to your modal and check if changed in `oncomponentdidchange` method?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.yourPoperty!== prevProps.yourPoperty) {
       //do your visibility stuff
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can do it with redux when you connect your components to the store.

Comment: The components that I want to manage their visibility are in the parent component, but the visibility change happens inside a modal. How will this work? Btw I use functional programming but I guess use effect can do the same job as componentdidupdate does...

Comment: Not really the same job, the componentDidUpdate is only called once when you use class syntax, useEffect is called at three different occasions: componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and componentWillUnmount. You can store your previous props and compare them to the new props when they arrive and set visibility on change of the props. More about the difference: https://linguinecode.com/post/react-componentdidupdate-vs-useeffect